# How do I add 2 columns to my Android SQLlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a `2.sql` file under `assets/migrations` with this

`ALTER TABLE Business ADD COLUMN name STRING;
ALTER TABLE Business ADD COLUMN time_zone STRING;`

I want to add 2 columns, one String and 1 Integer.

So I made `3.sql` in the same directory:

`ALTER TABLE Business ADD COLUMN background_image_uri STRING;
ALTER TABLE Business ADD COLUMN background_image_number INTEGER DEFAULT 0;`

and added this to `Business.java` under my `Class` definition:

```
@Column(name = "background_image_uri")
public String backgroundImageURI;

@Column(name = "background_image_number")
public int backgroundImageNumber;
```

I can set the variables fine, but it crashes when I try to save & load from disk.

How do I run this migration?

Comment: You are trying to load and save directly from `assets`?. Obviously not. You are copying to `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db`, **if the database doesn't already exist**. So, simply remove the db before starting the app and retry. This time it will be copied, and you can use it without any problem.

Comment: The database exists, I've already been working with an existing DB

Comment: But **it should not exist** in the target directory. Else, the new version **won't be copied** over the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Pull your DB from the phone/AVD (/data/data/your.package/...) to computer and browse it with SQLite3 DBMS (e. g. SQLiteman). You will understand what's the structure and what's going on.
Also you can put your stack trace here so we won't have to make predictions.